# HTML&CSS Управление с помощью чекбоксов

Tags: html, css

Короче, есть такой html фрагмент:
(чекбокс, может что-то другое, с возможностью двух положений - вкл/выкл)

```
<nav class="number">
         <a href="#" class="chapter_item">1</a>
         <a href="#" class="chapter_item">2</a>
         <a href="#" class="chapter_item">3</a>
</nav>
```

Нужно добавить кнопку над ссылками, при нажатии порядок навигации должен меняться. Пытался добавить чекбокс, и если он активен - менять свойство "flex-wrap" у *number*, но не получилось.
Как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Конкретизируйте. Вы или добавьте полный код воспроизводящий проблему (при редактировании вопроса нажмите Ctrl+M), или как-нибудь нарисуйте что хотите получить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы заработало это - надо флекс контейнер расположить под input с типом checkbox внутри label и выглядеть это будет вот так - смотрите

```css
span {
  user-select: none;
}

#queue {
  display: none;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#queue:checked~.flex {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<label for="queue">
    <span>Показать с конца</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="queue">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href="#">Первый в столбце</a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href="#">Второй в столбце</a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href="#">Третий в столбце</a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href="#">Четвёртый в столбце</a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href="#">Пятый в столбце</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
```

Comment: Такое у меня получалось сделать, но тут есть недостаток - порядок меняется в случае, если нажать правее/левее от текста, а нужно, чтобы нажатие меняло порядок только при нажатии на текст/кнопку "Показать с конца/Сменить порядок"
Если знаете способ, пожалуйста напишите. Спасибо

Comment: @EnderToy не понятно ...покажите пример ..ссылку где вы видели подобное

Comment: смотрите, есть список ссылок, а над ними должна быть кнопка, при нажатии на которую порядок списка отразится. Как пример:
https://remanga.org/manga/chiguhagu-na-karera-no-koi-no-yukue?subpath=content
Важно то, что я не хочу использовать js. Спасибо

Comment: @EnderToy наверно это не получится ....нужен js

Comment: да-а, я так и понял...